# SQL functions, calculating a result based on other values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with (Date(as date data type), Name, …) and i now want to add a column(on the right side), where it does something like this:

> If Month =<6 (fill the cell in the row) with S+YY(YY being the Year in the date column) else (fill the cell with W+YY).

I came up with this:

```sql
SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN MONTH(Termin) < 6 THEN 'S' + YEAR(Termin)
ELSE 'W' + YEAR(Termin) 
END as new_test FROM Prüfung; //Termin is the name of the column where the date format is in.
```

I am getting the error thingy saying that from is not in the right place?

```sql
CREATE TABLE  "PRÜFUNG" 
   (    "PRÜFUNG_ID" NUMBER(30,0), 
    "TERMIN" DATE, 
    "PRÜFUNGSFORM" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "RAUM_ID" NUMBER(30,0), 
    "MODUL_ID" NUMBER(30,0), 
    "LEHRVERANSTALTUNG_ID" NUMBER(30,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "PRÜFUNG_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PRÜFUNG_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
```

This is code i used to generate the table.

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you use and please add some sample data and the expected result, both as tables in your question. It's good you described what you want to do, but also showing it will make it even clearer. And please edit your question to add clarifications rather than doing this in comments.

Comment: Why do you refer to "cell"? Is the question for a spreadsheet? you also refer to a "date column" but we cannot see any columns at all - so we are flying blind. I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - oh, and please do NOT use images of data or of sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is using `EXTRACT` with `CASE`:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TERMIN) <= 6
THEN 'S' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TERMIN)
ELSE 'W' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TERMIN) END AS new_test
FROM PRÜFUNG;
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639) of `EXTRACT`.

An example similar to your sample data here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ELtiHPYJ)

If you need to select further columns, I highly recommend to do not use *, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select) why, but to write a proper column selection.

For example

```
SELECT
TERMIN, PRÜFUNGSFORM, 
CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TERMIN) <= 6
THEN 'S' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TERMIN)
ELSE 'W' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TERMIN) END AS new_test
FROM PRÜFUNG;
```

Comment: When i do this query: SELECT Termin, Prüfungsform, Raum_id, Modul_id, Lehrveranstaltung_id,
CASE WHEN EXTRACT (MONTH FROM TERMIN) <= 6
THEN 'S' || EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TERMIN)
ELSE 'W' || EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TERMIN) END AS test
FROM PRÜFUNG; I only get ‘Termin’ and ‘Prüfungsform’, what could cause this?This only happens in the application when i do it in the ‘terminal’ it works normal?

Comment: @Squallel This is another question and I think you should create a new question for that. It is difficult to say what is the reason of that issue without further information and we don't know which application or terminal you use.

Answer (score 0):

You try use this

```
SELECT *,
    
    CASE WHEN 
    
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TERMIN) <= 6 THEN
        
            'S' ||TO_CHAR(TERMIN,'YY') 
        ELSE
        
            'W' || TO_CHAR(TERMIN,'YY')  END as new_test 
        
    FROM Prüfung;
```